# MVC 3 RC 2 - Check model state to prevent postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing a postback of a partial view with the code below.  The controls in the partial view have mvc 3 rc 2 data annotations on them.  When I submit the form with errors the errors show on the controls but the form still gets submitted.  Is there a way to check the model state on the client side so that the $.post in the function below can be stopped from been executed.  Thanks.

```
$('#vehicleDetailsForm').submit(function () {

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (result) {
            $('#vehicleDetailsPartialView').html(result);
        });
        return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the jQuery validation plugin?  If so, you can run the validation using:

```
$('#vehicleDetailsForm').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (result) {
            $('#vehicleDetailsPartialView').html(result);
        });
    }
        return false; 
});
```

The same is probably true using the MS client validation library.  I'll see if I can find an example.

Comment: The `.valid()` method actually triggers the validation once again but I am not aware of any cleaner way to achieve this with the `jquery.validate` plugin.